# How to move up all elements' by manipulating top value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I have an ios lockscreen that I downloaded, that has multiple elements that display facts about the weather i.e. text, small images... anyways I want to know how to move them ALL up to the top of the screen, currently they are in the middle. every element has position absolute and different Z-indexes. Should I change the top: value? Should I group them, and if so how do I do this and move them all up?! Btw for those of you that don't know, all js, html, css is permitted in a lockscreen theme

**UPDATE** here is the code! -

```
<style type="text/css">
.weekday
{
position: absolute;
top: 252px;
left: -18px;
width: 320px;
height: 60px;
text-align:right;
font-family:source_sans_prolight;
font-weight:100;
font-size: 13px;
color: white;
text-transform:lowercase;
}
</style>



<style type="text/css" >
.month{
position: absolute;
top: 268px;
width: 320px;
left: -33px;
height: 60px;
text-align:right;
font-family:source_sans_prolight;
font-weight:100;
font-size: 13px;
color: white;
text-transform:lowercase;
}
</style>

<style type= "text/css">
.date{
position: absolute;
top: 268px;
width: 320px;
left: -18px;
text-align:right;
font-family:source_sans_prolight;
font-weight:100; font-size:
13px;
color: white;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
.icon{
position: absolute;
z-index:10;
left: 15px;
top: 200px;

}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
#temp{
position:absolute;
z-index:7;
color:white;
top: 251px;
left:40px;
width: 320px;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:200;
font-family: source_sans_prolight;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
#clock{
position:absolute;
width: 320px;
height: 200px;
left: -15px;
text-align: right;
z-index: +4;
top: 194px;
font-family: source_sans_prolight;
color:white;
font-size: 55px;
font-weight: 100;
}
</style>
```

there is more, but that is what is looks like!

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the source. But it sounds like changing the ```top``` values could be enough (if you simply want to move those elements from the middle to the top) since their position is set to ```absolute```.

Comment: After you updated your post I'd say you should be fine by simply altering the ```top``` values. A wrapper for your "widgets" is optional depending on how you would like to alter the layout and what the current layout looks like. For a more detailed answer you would have to give us a working example e.g. on jsfiddle.

Comment: I tried editing the top values, however there are too many to do each individually!

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult without you posting any code! TO answer your question of how to move them up to the top, I would add a container `<div>` element around the other elements, then set the CSS of that to be something like:

```
.lock-item-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

You might have to set a width depending upon how the child elements are positioned.
Hope this helps, if not please add some of your markup & CSS.